# how to find a class with BeautifulSoup4 when it is buried under other classes?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[HTML chunk that I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzgzh.png)

Hello!

long time lurker, first time poster. I have been playing around with BeautifulSoup4 using python version 3.11.7.

I am trying to get the text shown in the attached image that says "Huy Fong Sriracha Chili Sauce Hot 17oz. I have Successfully done this on a different website, however I have been trying this site for about 3 hours now with no success.

here is the class that I am trying to use. Please ignore how un-pythonic it is, I am still learning and list comprehension still kind of scares me. Once I know it works I will work on making it pretty.

```
class targetSearch:

    def __init__(self, UPC):

    ### soup control
        self.upc = UPC
        self.url = (("https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm="+self.upc))
        self.webpage = requests.get(self.url, headers=HEADERS)
        self.soup = bs(self.webpage.content, "html.parser")
        
    def search_results(self):
        self.results = []
        for result in (self.soup.find_all("a",class_ = 'data-test'))[:5]:
            result = result.get_text()
            print(result)
            self.results.append(result)
```

I have tried using different classes, as well as even trying to find it in the div instead of the anchor tag, finding it by searching for a string containing the class name, and just about everything else. I'm sure I am missing something silly, but I am not sure what it is.

any help would be greatly appreciated! part of the thing I have found that I like so much about coding (and especially webscraping) is the puzzle-like nature of it, but I think I am at a spot that I need some help.

EDITS:

I will make this edit to address a few comments that I have received.

```
    <a href="/p/huy-fong-sriracha-chili-sauce-hot-17oz/-/A-13334650#lnk=sametab"
 aria-label="Huy Fong Sriracha Chili Sauce Hot 17oz" 
 class="styles__StyledLink-sc-vpsldm-0 styles__StyledTitleLink-sc-14ktig2-1 cbOry csOImU h-display-block h-text-bold h-text-bs" 
 data-test="product-title">Huy Fong Sriracha Chili Sauce Hot 17oz</a>
```

is the chunk of HTML that I am trying to scrape, and when I call the search result method that I posted it returns an empty list

Comment: Please post the HTML as text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: the code itself looks good (except the slice `[:5]`)... it's not clear what you get back... error? other result? Maybe `class_='data-test'` is wrong, `a`-tag has no class attribute: `data-test="product-title"`?

Comment: @toyotaSupra good call, i have made an edit posting the HTML in this format.

Comment: @cards the [:5] was intended to make sure i only grabbed the first five results, although I am sure there is a better way to do it.  i just tried using "data-test", class_="product-title", but it still returned an empty list

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `search_results` with a more refined filter criteria. As mentioned in the comment `class_='data-test'` is wrong. Here an example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<a
    href       = "/p/huy-fong-sriracha-chili-sauce-hot-17oz/-/A-13334650#lnk=sametab"
    aria-label = "Huy Fong Sriracha Chili Sauce Hot 17oz" 
    class      = "styles__StyledLink-sc-vpsldm-0 styles__StyledTitleLink-sc-14ktig2-1 cbOry csOImU h-display-block h-text-bold h-text-bs" 
    data-test  = "product-title">
  Huy Fong Sriracha Chili Sauce Hot 17oz
</a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# description of the attributes to uniquely identify the tag(s)
a_tag_ids = {
    "href":       True,
    "aria-label": True,
    'class':      True,
    'data-test':  'product-title'
}

for a in soup.find_all("a", a_tag_ids, string=True):
    print(a.get_text(strip=True))
```

Notice further that in this case the attributes are passed as dictionary because `data-test='product-title'` cannot be passed as it to the `find_method` due to the `-` symbol in the keyword.

In my answer the filter criteria are a bit *excessive*, tune them properly accordingly to the rest of the page.

Comment: first off I would like to thank you for your answer, it seriously helped me understand a lot of things about beautiful soup that i was unsure of.  on my end, however, i am still just getting an empty list returned. I'm not sure if you can tell, but I am trying to scrape Targets' website for search results based on UPC codes. the UPC code for sriracha is 024463061095. could you possibly pop that into the target.com search bar and inspect the HTML, and maybe let me know if you see any reason that it wouldn't work? I would really appreciate it.  in the meantime I will continue to try.

Comment: I strongly believe that the wep-page contains JavaScript, so it's dynamically rendered, and requests doesn't _explicitly_ support it... that's why you get back an empty list. You should look at the content of the `<script>` tag (very annoying) or use another technology requests_html, selenium

Comment: as an exercise you could copy-paste the source code of the page from the browser (smt like right click, View Page Source) and scrape it. If it works than you can conclude that the page is dynamically rendered

Comment: I will try you suggestion when I get home later today. I suspected that the page may be dynamically rendered, however when I disabled Javascript in Chrome the page still loaded correctly so I was unsure. I would like to try to avoid using selenium if possible, do you know of a way to make this work with bs4? I don't need a step by step instruction, just a heads up on a place to start looking